# Take a dictionary representation of a directed graph, and returns a dictionary representation of its underlying undirected graph

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that takes a dictionary representation of a directed graph, and returns a dictionary representation of its underlying undirected graph.

For example, if the following dictionary representation of the following graph is:

```
d = {1 : [4],

   2 : [3],

   3 : [1, 6],

   4 : [6],

   5 : [1],

   6 : [5]}
```

[graph1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0jQd.jpg)

The dictionary representation of its underlying simple graph is:

```
d = {1 : [3, 4, 5],

    2 : [3],

    3 : [1, 2, 6],

    4 : [1, 6]

    5 : [1, 6],

    6 : [3, 5] }
```

[graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CexoO.jpg)

---

I am kind of stuck on how to go about solving
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the graph undirected, you need to add each key as value if it is not already present:

```
for k,l in d.items():
    for e in l:
        if k not in d[e]:
            d[e].append(k)
```

output:

```
{1: [4, 3, 5],
 2: [3],
 3: [1, 6, 2],
 4: [6, 1],
 5: [1, 6],
 6: [5, 3, 4]}
```